# Python: sqlalchemy - map result only

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have some sql to run which is not single table based. Below is one example(on sqlite)

```
SELECT C.REGION METRICSCOPE, C.METRIC METRICOPTION, ROUND(1.0*C.COUNT/T.COUNT, 4) Percentage, T.COUNT COUNT
FROM
 (SELECT REGION, $metric METRIC, COUNT(*) COUNT
 FROM TICKET T, USER U
 WHERE T.ASSIGNEDTO = U.USERNAME
 AND ASOF BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'
 GROUP BY REGION, $metric ) C,
 (SELECT REGION, COUNT(*) COUNT
FROM TICKET T, USER U
WHERE ASOF BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'
AND T.ASSIGNEDTO = U.USERNAME
GROUP BY region) T
WHERE C.REGION = T.REGION
```

I want to run the sql and then map the result to a class, then jsonify the class objects & return to my webpage.
It seems to me that sqlalchemy use the table based map(each class needs to define the tablename) which is not suitable for my case.
Is it possible to map the result only? Appreciate if you can provide an example for me.
Thanks

Comment: You can execute raw SQL in SQLAlchemy if you don't want to use objects.

Comment: Thanks  @snakecharmerb. I want to use semi-orm, i want to map the result to the object only without have to bind the class to the table. Is it doable?